# Python not reading last line from file

Tags: python, file, text

I pull some data from DB and save it to a text file called "databaseoutput.txt". When I run the code below all lines are displayed except the last one - and I know it's there because when I open the file the line that's missing when I run the code below is present

```
with open("databaseoutput.txt", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

What can be causing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that code.  Does the file contain formatting characters (such as linefeeds) that could alter the on-screen appearance of the output?

Comment: I tried the code myself and everything is working fine. Can you provide your databaseoutput.txt ?

Comment: @epsilonmajorquezero unfortunately I can't as this company's data but what I can say is the last 3 lines will be something like:

*userA
*userB
*userC

So I would assume they're similar and if the line second and third from the and are read then the last would be read too

Comment: I deleted my wrong answer. Seems like a problem with the encoding.

Comment: This shouldn't cause any issue, and actually tried and nothing is wrong with that char.

Comment: @Seb_ Try reading without the encoding (Either with 'r' or 'rb') and see if the last line appears there.

Comment: @echefede I've removed the encoding and still the same

Comment: Without a [mcve] there's nothing more we can do, except state the obvious; this code *should* work (even if the file lacks a final newline, for example).

Comment: @Seb_ look for the actual file encoding

Comment: If you change the print statement to some fixed message, like `print("hello")`, does it print the correct amount of times?

Comment: Demo, no repro: https://ideone.com/7e3guG

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem as you. When creating my text file I forgot to close it with:

```
f.close()
```